# jquery, ui tabs nav animated and I need it to not animate if its li.ui-tabs-selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This page is live at http://settlementprep.com/services/

```
$("#services_nav li a.move ").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':"20px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':"0px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
    });
```

this animates all the navigation items.  But I want to have the current li be stuck up and not go back down, but I also don't want it to slide up while its already up... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add class 'active' to the link that was clicked. And add CSS accordingly. See the sample code below:

```
var $serviceLinks = $("#services_nav .move");
$serviceLinks.hover(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
        $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':"20px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
}, function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
        $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':"0px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
});

$serviceLinks.click(function(){

    $serviceLinks.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

}
```

Comment: So I implemented this code and while it works, the .active item can still be slid up on mouseover.  take a look and let me know what you think.  I would like to remove the .active element from sliding up

Comment: Just check if the link doesn't have 'active' class before animating it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping when the mouse leaves, the elements now drop when a new element is hovered:

```
$("#services_nav li a.move ").hover(function(){
            $("#services_nav li a.move ").each(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':"0px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
            });
            $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':"20px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
        });
```